# Porting Windows Phone game with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monogame

I currently have a very simple memory game for Windows Phone that I would like to port over to iOS, Android and possibly Win8 using Xamarin tools.

I would like to centralize my business logic in one assembly and simply create the UI for each platform.

For the most part, the code is simple C#, but I do make use of Bitmaps to show the cards in the game. However, from what I've read, there is no standard support across the different platforms for using Bitmaps.

What would be a recommended approach to this problem?

I'm thinking I have to use something like MonoGame, but feel that is overkill for what I want to do.

Comment: If you are referring to image bitmaps, then you can use the iOS/Android equivalents for image views or monogame according to your discretion.  However, if you are referring to the System.Drawing.Bitmap object then you will need to use something else as Bitmap objects are not available in the current stable release of Mono for iOS/Android.  In that case I would recommend MonoGame.

Comment: My biggest concern was having a cross-platform way to read images (PNG). Looks like my best option will be to use Texture2D which is supported in MonoGame. The pluralsight course on MonoGame was very helpful http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/monogame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say your code is in C#. As far as I know Xamarin is the only way to get C# code to run on Android and iOS. Xamarin has a free starter edition that you *might* be able to use but your app will be size limited. Once you hit the size limit you'll need to pay for a license.

After you've decided to pay for a license there are no other costs involved if you want to use MonoGame for the port. If your game is already using XNA or you have some XNA experience I  recommend using MonoGame. MonoGame is a port of XNA and is designed for making games, so many game related tasks are easier.

The alternative is to build your game as an app using the standard app building API. This is possible but I can't see any advantages doing it this way unless you are trying to save money by using Xamarin's free edition. If you plan to make more games in the future, you'd be better off biting the bullet and learning MonoGame.

Using bitmaps with MonoGame shouldn't be a problem. Although, you may need to convert them to PNG's first.

Centralizing the business logic in one assembly is sort of possible using Portable Class Libraries but due to the limitations of PCL's it's often easier to use file sharing. Basically you have a soft link to the files in each project. Updating the files updates them in all projects at the same time, but adding new files requires you to add them to each project individually. It's a little bit of a maintenance pain, but not much.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, as a starting point you should separate UI and logic.

To reach this I highly recommend you to make `console` version of game. Using console it is possible only send commands with parameters to application. No mouse or real-time keyboards usages. All UI-related tasks will be left. Only business logic and commands to use will remain.

Then, you should try `MonoGame`. It's reliable enough for 2D games. Even more, If IL-code is not too much, it's free for `iOS` and `Android`!

Other way is... `Unity 3D`. Using that engine is depends of code you wrote. In some cases it's possible to use that game engine with shared business logic. Thanks to new [Unity 3D policy](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/05/21/putting-the-power-of-unity-in-the-hands-of-every-mobile-developer/), indie game developers could make and deploy their games for free.

In short, plan is:

- Implement core functionality (with console I/O);
- Then, choose engine and implement UI for target platforms.

Comment: To make use of images/bitmaps does it require I use a third-party library like MonoGames or Unity? Or are there parts of .NET that support images/bitmaps that are present in the different platforms?

Comment: In short, no. For any target platform you will have image files or byte arrays (packed resources), which one you should draw using target platform API. For example, to show image in `iOS` it could be `UIImageView`, in `Android` it could be `ImageView`, which is slightly different from `iOS` version. Thus `UI` code will be relatively big. The point of `MonoGame` or Unity is to share even `UI` code. For any target platform showing images in `MonoGame` could be done via `Texture2D` class. The same is for `Unity`.